# Изменение запроса, equals и is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, orm

Доброго времени суток! Мне необходимо получить записи не только с родителями, но и без, для которых ParentTitle будет равен null. Каким образом изменить запрос?

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> myData = 
    from m in t.YourEntity
    join e1 in t.YourEntity on m.ParentId equals e1.Id
    select new MyClass
    { 
        Id = m.Id,
        ParentId = m.ParentId,
        Title = m.Title,
        ParentTitle = e1.Title,
        Created = m.Created,
        Description = m.Description
    };

    return View(myData.ToList());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо использовать `left outer join`

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> myData = 
    from m in t.YourEntity
    join e1 in t.YourEntity on m.ParentId equals e1.Id into ee
    from e in ee.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new MyClass
    { 
        Id = m.Id,
        ParentId = m.ParentId,
        Title = m.Title,
        ParentTitle = e?.Title,
        Created = m.Created,
        Description = m.Description
    };

    return View(myData.ToList());
```

Документация - https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Join-Operators-dabef4e9#leftouterjoin